# Can't get Visual Studio to allow me to debug, only "Attach"

Tags: visual-studio-2017

When I am trying to run a program in Visual Studio, I do not have the option to debug the program. I only have the option to "Attach". I have looked up other solutions to this problem but I do not have anything to solve the problem. I will be attaching an image to this post. Thank you in advance for your time.

[image]

- Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017

  - Version 15.9.5
- Microsoft .NET Framework

  - Version 4.7.03056

Comment: Do you have your build configuration in Release or Debug?  Edit your question to provide the necessary information required to answer your question.

Comment: Why did you copy and paste and provide every Visual Studio extension you have installed?  You failed to indicate if you have your project in Debug or Release configuration.

Comment: Where do I find that?

Comment: Did you open a project or a single file? Is this your program or someone elses? How much experience do you have with Visual Studio and C++?

Comment: I opened a file. I have a little experience but not much. I opened a file for my class that I'm in.

Comment: @Letholor - You need to add your source file to a project solution.  The project configuration (Release, Debug) would be next to the words the "run icon" within Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't debug a single file, you'll need to open a Solution(.sln) or Project (.vcxproj) instead. The Solution/Project contains all the configuration, settings and files needed for the program. Inside the folder you got from school should be a .sln or .vcxproj file (or both). Solutions can hold multiple Projects. Projects are the individual programs you're writing. Open that and try debugging again.

Comment: It seems that I need to notify my professor that I was not given the solution file. That explains why I couldn't find it while trying to open it from Visual Studio.